# Count of rows for a particular column and display with the last row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to count the rows for a same values in a column and display the count value with the last column. Below is my scenario

Table 1

```
Col_A  Col_B   Col_C
a      1       a1
a      2       a2
a      3       a3
a      4       a4
a      5       a5
a      6       a6
b      7       a7
b      8       a8
b      9       a9
b      10      a10
e      7       a11
e      1       a12
e      4       a13
```

while displaying the data I should count same value in COL_A and display as shown below

```
Col_A  Col_B   Col_C   Col_D
a      1       a1   
a      2       a2   
a      3       a3   
a      4       a4   
a      5       a5   
a      6       a6      6
b      7       a7   
b      8       a8   
b      9       a9   
b      10      a10     4
e      7       a11  
e      1       a12  
e      4       a13     3
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why?   It would be better to do this in the front end.

Comment: This is to do the automation testing and validate the data

Comment: It would be easier to paste your current results into Excel and do it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check to see if the row_number is equal to the count() over() and if so display the count

```
SELECT  [Col_A], 
        [Col_B], 
        [Col_C],
        (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Col_A] ORDER BY [Col_B]) = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_A) 
            THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY COL_A) END) AS Col_D
FROM    Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Lead() is used to check if this is the last row of the set and row_number is used to calculate the amount of rows:

```
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, case when isnull(NextA,'') != Col_A then RN end
from (
  select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by Col_A order by Col_C) as RN,
    lead(Col_A) over (order by Col_A, Col_C) as NextA
  from Table1
) X
```

For 2008 using row number in reverse should work too:

```
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C, case when RN2 = 1 then RN end
from (
  select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by Col_A order by Col_C asc) as RN,
    row_number() over (partition by Col_A order by Col_C desc) as RN2
  from Table1
) X
```

Comment: Thank you JamesZ for the input and I just realized that we are in SQL Server 2008 :-(

Comment: @Gaurav Well you can do it with row_number too, added that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2008 has `ROW_NUMBER()`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YTF29427)**

```
SELECT X.*,  (CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN total END) as count_A
FROM ( SELECT Col_A, 
              Col_B, 
              Col_C, 
              row_number() over 
                (partition by Col_A order by Col_C DESC) as rn
       from test
     ) X
join (
       SELECT [Col_A] , 
              count([Col_A]) as total
       FROM test GROUP BY [Col_A]
    ) Y
   ON X.[Col_A] = Y.[Col_A]
ORDER BY X.Col_A,          
         X.Col_C
```

OUTPUT

[image]

**EDIT v2.0:** This probably should work too and doesnt need `JOIN`

```
SELECT X.*, 
       (CASE WHEN rn=1 
             THEN MAX(rn) OVER (partition BY X.col_a) 
        END) as count_A 
FROM ( SELECT Col_A, 
              Col_B, 
              Col_C, 
              row_number() over (partition by Col_A order by Col_C DESC) as rn
       from test
     ) X
ORDER BY X.Col_A,          
         X.Col_C
```

Comment: Thank you Juan and I tried this query and it worked.